# How do I read knife stats?

Tags: payday-2

The damage and knockdown stats are confusing me. What's the difference between the value and the value in brackets? Why is 15(75) better than 20(52)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The value not in brackets is the damage for a single strike with that melee weapon. The value in brackets is the damage of a "fully charged" strike with the same weapon (you can hold down the melee button to "charge" a strike with certain weapons). You can see the charge time below the knockdown damage.

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't even consider you could charge it, and thought the charge time was simply the time between attacks. Thanks!